# Can I determine whether a Ctrl key press is Left Ctrl or Right Ctrl?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to determine whether a <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key is <kbd>LEFT CTRL</kbd> or <kbd>RIGHT CTRL</kbd> key when it is pressed. How can I do this?

Comment: What have you got so far ? Also, any specific reason why you want to differentiate between the two ?

Comment: Can you give additional details?

Comment: Since no one else has asked...why would you want to differentiate between the two?

Comment: I am making small game in C# so I want to do this. plz don't ask reason............

Comment: @Govind, it is generally acceptable to ask why you want to do something.  For example, you said you're developing a game, have you perhaps looked at XNA (a .NET system which you can program in C#).  XNA has native support for distinguishing individual key presses.

Comment: @Ray Hayes thanks I will never write that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:
You can now use `System.Windows.Input.Keybaord.IsKeyDown()`

- see the other answers above. Historically you couldn't access this information from within .net - so it was necessary to do the following:

> However, you can use the Win32 API `GetAsyncKeyState` to test if specific keys are currently down, and this can differentiate the left and right ctrl keys. (If you're writing a game this is more likely to work well for you than Keydown handlers, as GetAsyncKeyState tests whether the key is down "now" rather than whether it was pressed "at some time in the past", which gives considerably better responsiveness).

Comment: This is no longer the correct answer - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49847252/4658148

Comment: Thanks @JacekKołodziejek - answer edited to make this clearer.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily check the status of the Keyboard using `System.Windows.Input.Keybaord.IsKeyDown()` to determine if the `Right` or `Left` `Control` key is pressed:

```
if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl)
     {}
else if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl)
     {}
end if
```

Comment: To clarify, the System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.IsKeyDown() method requires PresentationCore.dll (Add Reference -> Assembies -> Framework -> PresentationCore). The System.Windows.Input.Key enum is defined in WindowsBase.dll (Add Reference -> Assembies -> Framework -> WindowsBase).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently not from within .NET, but it's possible from the Win32 APIs.

- The [System.Windows.Forms.Key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) enumeration tracks left, right, and middle mouse buttons, but only has one flag for Control keys, so no way to determine left or right for Control keys.
- The [Console.ReadKey() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) suffers from the same problem.
- You might be able to do something at the Win32 level.  The [WM_KEYDOWN message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646280%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) will track the extended keys (right Alt, right Control), so Windows is tracking this data ... it just isn't being passed on to .NET.  You're on your own with regard to tapping into the Win32 API from within .NET.