# C# Register Key Press for Ctrl and another key at the same time?

Tags: c#

Source: [How do I detect keyPress while not focused?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18291448/how-do-i-detect-keypress-while-not-focused/23955334#23955334)

I have read a tutorial about how to register a key, even when the window is not in the focus.
This really hepled me, but I would like to check, if the Control (Ctrl) -Key is pressed as well at the same moment.

I tried this, but it didn't help:

```
if (ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
{
     //do stuff...
}
```

To be exactly, it required both Control-Keys (left and right) to be pressed at that moment to trigger...

Comment: This has been covered close to a half dozen times on Stack Overflow alone.

Comment: It depends, do you require the window _not to be focused_?

Comment: The thing is, I don't have KeyEventArgs e...

The method has no parameters.

Comment: That's not a valid duplicate, This question mentions checking for both control keys potentially without window focus, while the duplicate checks for Ctrl+Shift in a key down event. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035111/can-i-determine-whether-a-ctrl-key-press-is-left-ctrl-or-right-ctrl) for left vs right ctrl